# Manually end a toast using Vue-toastification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toast

Good day,

I am currently using Vue-toastification and I wanted to ask if it's possible to manually end a toast notification? I have searched the docs and I couldn't find it.

My goal is that when another toast notification pops up the 1st one should be deleted. I now have hardcoded timeouts, but the time can vary and it's sometimes not very precise.

Here is my toast.

```js
this.$toast.info("Please hold on a moment, your file is being downloaded.");
```

I have tried both toast.close() and toast.remove(), but this doesn't yield the expected result.

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification#dismiss-toasts-programmatically)

Comment: @gre_gor my man, I read it. I missed it. This happens. Someone already answered so I don't know the purpose of your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```js
const id = this.$toast.info("Please hold on a moment, your file is being downloaded.")

// dismiss
this.$toast.dismiss(id)
```